# .Net Library with similar function to google prediction API

Tags: c#, .net, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, neural-network

Google prediction API is awesome, it has text classification also, mixed mode classification, and many more... but it is too costly to use for all softwares.

Is there any .net alternative, which provides similar functionality to google prediction api?
must have text classification.

NOTE: new to artificial intelligence, classification.

Answer (score 0):

Google Prediction API likely uses technologies like neural networks and machine learning to classify and predict things. Its a vast subject and quite complex mathematically, but there are certainly some .NET libraries out there that take a lot of the hard work out of it.

For example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/aforge_neuro.aspx) is a CodeProject article that covers the [AForge.Neuro](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/) library.

Answer (score 0):

Encog is a more actively developed project, in terms of machine learning.

Have a look at http://www.heatonresearch.com/encog